# Jquery Div Changes Not Affected With in the Script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a div with multiple dropdowns. The dropdowns doesn't have any id. I am working with some other logic to remove and add the dropdowns within the div. If i remove a dropdown means the changes doesn't affect with in the same script.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () { 
   alert($('#show_lable_categories').find('select').length)); // return 5
   //Now Remove some dropdowns
   $('#show_value_categories').find("select").slice(2).remove();
   alert($('#show_lable_categories').find('select').length)); //Always return 5 //I need 3 Instead of 5 with in the script

});
});
```

Comment: could you please HTML also?

Comment: It's a typo, you wrote "show_value_categories" instead of "show_lable_categories"

Comment: better if you could create a similar [demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

```
 $('#show_value_categories').find("select").slice(2).remove();
```

I think the issue might be that you made a typo on the element you are selecting, which changes from $('#show_value_categories') to $('#show_lable_categories').

Also just as tip, you want to have a variable such as:

```
var dropdown = $('#show_value_categories')
```

to avoid bugs such as these as well as not have to find the same element twice.